# Omnipay error for paypal express checkout, your last action could not be completed

Tags: paypal, laravel, laravel-4, omnipay

I am using OmniPay for paypal express payment with laravel. One time it worked. But now it is only breaking into the paypal page with the following error:

> Sorry — your last action could not be completed If you were making a
>   purchase or sending money, we recommend that you check both your
>   PayPal account and your email for a transaction confirmation after 30
>   minutes.
>
> If you came to this page from another website, please return to that
>   site (don't use your browser's Back button) and restart your activity.
>
> If you came from PayPal's website, click the PayPal logo in the
>   upper-left corner to return to our home page and restart your
>   activity. You might have to log in again.
>
> Dispatch Error, please check logfile for more information

```
public function paypal() {
        $gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');
        $gateway->setUsername('XXXXX');
        $gateway->setPassword('XXXXX');
        $gateway->setSignature('XXXXX');
        $gateway->setTestMode(true);

        $bookX=new BookingEx();
        $bookX=unserialize(\Session::get('booking_data'));

        $args = array('amount' => $bookX->total,
            'returnUrl' => 'http://localhost:8000/booking/paypal-return',
            'cancelUrl' => 'http://localhost:8000/booking/paypal-cancel',
            'description' => 'Your booking $ limousinesydneyaustralia.com',
            'currency'=>'USD');

        $response = $gateway->purchase($args)->send();

        if ($response->isRedirect()) {
            $response->redirect();
        } else {
            //display error
        }
    }
```

Any idea please?

Updated:
Here is what I get just after I call purchase method:

```
    > Omnipay\PayPal\Message\ExpressAuthorizeResponse Object (
    > [liveCheckoutEndpoint:protected] => https://www.paypal.com/webscr
    > [testCheckoutEndpoint:protected] =>
    > https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr [request:protected] =>
    > Omnipay\PayPal\Message\ExpressAuthorizeRequest Object (
    > [liveEndpoint:protected] => https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
    > [testEndpoint:protected] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
    > [parameters:protected] =>
    > Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object (
    > [parameters:protected] => Array ( [username] =>
    > tesll.xyx_api1.gmail.com [password] => 3440459909 [signature] =>
    > AftOquNmMEiTzuUdbQfXGh6QneRPAzxoLwkQKC0nlNPES4ot7707vkoJ [testMode] =>
    > 1 [solutionType] => Sole [landingPage] => Billing [brandName] =>
    > [headerImageUrl] => [amount] => 16.37 [returnUrl] =>
    > http://localhost:8000/booking/paypal-return [cancelUrl] =>
    > http://localhost:8000/booking/paypal-cancel [description] => Your
    > booking $ limousinesydneyaustralia.com [currency] => USD ) )
    > [httpClient:protected] => Guzzle\Http\Client Object (
    > [defaultHeaders:protected] => Guzzle\Common\Collection Object (
    > [data:protected] => Array ( ) ) [userAgent:protected] => Guzzle/3.9.1
    > curl/7.30.0 PHP/5.5.9 [config:Guzzle\Http\Client:private] =>
    > Guzzle\Common\Collection Object ( [data:protected] => Array (
    > [curl.options] => Array ( [78] => 60 [10065] =>
    > C:\xampp\htdocs\sangam\vendor\guzzle\http\Guzzle\Http/Resources/cacert.pem
    > [64] => 1 [81] => 2 ) ) ) [baseUrl:Guzzle\Http\Client:private] =>
    > [curlMulti:Guzzle\Http\Client:private] =>
    > Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMultiProxy Object ( [handles:protected] => Array
    > ( [0] => Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti Object ( [multiHandle:protected]
    > => Resource id #198 [requests:protected] => Array ( ) [handles:protected] => SplObjectStorage Object (
    > [storage:SplObjectStorage:private] => Array ( ) )
    > [resourceHash:protected] => Array ( ) [exceptions:protected] => Array
    > ( ) [successful:protected] => Array ( ) [multiErrors:protected] =>
    > Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => CURLM_BAD_HANDLE [1] => The passed-in
    > handle is not a valid CURLM handle. ) [2] => Array ( [0] =>
    > CURLM_BAD_EASY_HANDLE [1] => An easy handle was not good/valid. It
    > could mean that it isn't an easy handle at all, or possibly that the
    > handle already is in used by this or another multi handle. ) [3] =>
    > Array ( [0] => CURLM_OUT_OF_MEMORY [1] => You are doomed. ) [4] =>
    > Array ( [0] => CURLM_INTERNAL_ERROR [1] => This can only be returned
    > if libcurl bugs. Please report it to us! ) ) [selectTimeout:protected]
    > => 1 [eventDispatcher:protected] => Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher Object (
    > [listeners:Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher:private]
    > => Array ( ) [sorted:Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher:private] =>
    > Array ( ) ) ) ) [groups:protected] => Array ( ) [queued:protected] =>
    > Array ( ) [maxHandles:protected] => 3 [selectTimeout:protected] => 1
    > [eventDispatcher:protected] =>
    > Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher Object (
    > [listeners:Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher:private]
    > => Array ( ) [sorted:Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher:private] =>
    > Array ( ) ) ) [uriTemplate:Guzzle\Http\Client:private] =>
    > Guzzle\Parser\UriTemplate\UriTemplate Object (
    > [template:Guzzle\Parser\UriTemplate\UriTemplate:private] =>
    > [variables:Guzzle\Parser\UriTemplate\UriTemplate:private] =>
    > [regex:Guzzle\Parser\UriTemplate\UriTemplate:private] =>
    > /\{([^\}]+)\}/ ) [requestFactory:protected] =>
    > Guzzle\Http\Message\RequestFactory Object ( [methods:protected] =>
    > Array ( [getInstance] => 0 [__construct] => 1 [fromMessage] => 2
    > [fromParts] => 3 [create] => 4 [cloneRequestWithMethod] => 5
    > [applyOptions] => 6 [visit_headers] => 7 [visit_body] => 8
    > [visit_allow_redirects] => 9 [visit_auth] => 10 [visit_query] => 11
    > [visit_cookies] => 12 [visit_events] => 13 [visit_plugins] => 14
    > [visit_exceptions] => 15 [visit_save_to] => 16 [visit_params] => 17
    > [visit_timeout] => 18 [visit_connect_timeout] => 19 [visit_debug] =>
    > 20 [visit_verify] => 21 [visit_proxy] => 22 [visit_cert] => 23
    > [visit_ssl_key] => 24 ) [requestClass:protected] =>
    > Guzzle\Http\Message\Request [entityEnclosingRequestClass:protected] =>
    > Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest )
    > [eventDispatcher:protected] =>
    > Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher Object (
    > [listeners:Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher:private]
    > => Array ( [request.sent] => Array ( [100] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Guzzle\Http\RedirectPlugin Object (
    > [defaultMaxRedirects:protected] => 5 ) [1] => onRequestSent ) ) )
    > [request.clone] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
    > Guzzle\Http\RedirectPlugin Object ( [defaultMaxRedirects:protected] =>
    > 5 ) [1] => cleanupRequest ) ) ) [request.before_send] => Array ( [0]
    > => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Guzzle\Http\RedirectPlugin Object ( [defaultMaxRedirects:protected] => 5 ) [1] => cleanupRequest ) ) ) )
    > [sorted:Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher:private] =>
    > Array ( ) ) ) [httpRequest:protected] =>
    > Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request Object ( [attributes] =>
    > Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object (
    > [parameters:protected] => Array ( ) ) [request] =>
    > Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object (
    > [parameters:protected] => Array ( ) ) [query] =>
    > Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object (
    > [parameters:protected] => Array ( ) ) [server] =>
    > Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag Object (
    > [parameters:protected] => Array ( [DOCUMENT_ROOT] =>
    > C:\xampp\htdocs\sangam\public [REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1 [REMOTE_PORT]
    > => 64532 [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => PHP 5.5.9 Development Server [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1 [SERVER_NAME] => localhost [SERVER_PORT]
    > => 8000 [REQUEST_URI] => /booking/pay-with-paypal [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php [SCRIPT_FILENAME] =>
    > C:\xampp\htdocs\sangam\public\index.php [PATH_INFO] =>
    > /booking/pay-with-paypal [PHP_SELF] =>
    > /index.php/booking/pay-with-paypal [HTTP_HOST] => localhost:8000
    > [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
    > [HTTP_ACCEPT] =>
    > text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    > [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
    > AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137
    > Safari/537.36 [HTTP_REFERER] => http://localhost:8000/booking/
    > [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip,deflate,sdch [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] =>
    > en-US,en;q=0.8,hi;q=0.6 [HTTP_COOKIE] =>
    > laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Im1NcEJwMkduMTRRdGRKVXZaR1IrOUxlSmxnVmhFZjE3Umc5MWxwRUpIVDg9IiwidmFsdWUiOiJjekp6Tjk2ZU1pZUpvTzR1MjV6eldLTGJuaXhiWW1tYzV1Z1NveFJVK25oNlRyMjgyNmNEdzZmeUNqS3lwZTAwcmVERk1rdHFyUE1nQnc1MVRkb2F6dz09IiwibWFjIjoiNGM4N2UyOTVhOThkMjRhMTAyZTI2ZDhlNTY5M2MyMjk4OGFhYzM5MGE4ZDY1ODE4MTcyYzlkNzNkMjIzZTY0ZSJ9
    > [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1400582955.8832 [REQUEST_TIME] => 1400582955 )
    > ) [files] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag Object (
    > [parameters:protected] => Array ( ) ) [cookies] =>
    > Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object (
    > [parameters:protected] => Array ( [laravel_session] =>
    > eyJpdiI6Im1NcEJwMkduMTRRdGRKVXZaR1IrOUxlSmxnVmhFZjE3Umc5MWxwRUpIVDg9IiwidmFsdWUiOiJjekp6Tjk2ZU1pZUpvTzR1MjV6eldLTGJuaXhiWW1tYzV1Z1NveFJVK25oNlRyMjgyNmNEdzZmeUNqS3lwZTAwcmVERk1rdHFyUE1nQnc1MVRkb2F6dz09IiwibWFjIjoiNGM4N2UyOTVhOThkMjRhMTAyZTI2ZDhlNTY5M2MyMjk4OGFhYzM5MGE4ZDY1ODE4MTcyYzlkNzNkMjIzZTY0ZSJ9
    > ) ) [headers] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag Object (
    > [headers:protected] => Array ( [host] => Array ( [0] => localhost:8000
    > ) [connection] => Array ( [0] => keep-alive ) [cache-control] => Array
    > ( [0] => max-age=0 ) [accept] => Array ( [0] =>
    > text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    > ) [user-agent] => Array ( [0] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
    > AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137
    > Safari/537.36 ) [referer] => Array ( [0] =>
    > http://localhost:8000/booking/ ) [accept-encoding] => Array ( [0] =>
    > gzip,deflate,sdch ) [accept-language] => Array ( [0] =>
    > en-US,en;q=0.8,hi;q=0.6 ) [cookie] => Array ( [0] =>
    > laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Im1NcEJwMkduMTRRdGRKVXZaR1IrOUxlSmxnVmhFZjE3Umc5MWxwRUpIVDg9IiwidmFsdWUiOiJjekp6Tjk2ZU1pZUpvTzR1MjV6eldLTGJuaXhiWW1tYzV1Z1NveFJVK25oNlRyMjgyNmNEdzZmeUNqS3lwZTAwcmVERk1rdHFyUE1nQnc1MVRkb2F6dz09IiwibWFjIjoiNGM4N2UyOTVhOThkMjRhMTAyZTI2ZDhlNTY5M2MyMjk4OGFhYzM5MGE4ZDY1ODE4MTcyYzlkNzNkMjIzZTY0ZSJ9
    > ) ) [cacheControl:protected] => Array ( [max-age] => 0 ) )
    > [content:protected] => [languages:protected] => [charsets:protected]
    > => [encodings:protected] => [acceptableContentTypes:protected] => [pathInfo:protected] => [requestUri:protected] => [baseUrl:protected]
    > => [basePath:protected] => [method:protected] => [format:protected] => [session:protected] => [locale:protected] => [defaultLocale:protected]
    > => en ) [response:protected] => Omnipay\PayPal\Message\ExpressAuthorizeResponse Object *RECURSION* )
    > [data:protected] => Array ( [TOKEN] => EC-4SW489106W090020K
    > [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-05-20T10:49:17Z [CORRELATIONID] => 9ecd1fa3cfd95
    > [ACK] => Success [VERSION] => 85.0 [BUILD] => 11024577 ) )
```

Update#2 
Just now I got the following additional error message at the bottom of the error message I talked about above. I hope this will help understand the error better.

MayflyNG::MayflyException: IOException: no response from 10.72.108.213:11068 Backtrace: MayflyNG::Client::rpc(MayflyNG::RequestMsg&, MayflyNG::ResponseMsg&, bool, CalTransaction&) MayflyNG::Client::internal_get(MayflyNG::RequestMsg&, MayflyNG::ResponseMsg&, Buffer*, MayflyNG::Context*, bool, CalTransaction&) MayflyNG::Client::handle_request(MayflyNG::Client::RequestMode::RequestType, MayflyNG::RequestMsg&, MayflyNG::ResponseMsg&, Buffer*, MayflyNG::Context*, CalTransaction&) MayflyNG::Client::get(Buffer const&, Buffer&, MayflyNG::Context*, int) MayflyNG::Client::get(String const&, Buffer&, MayflyNG::Context*, int) Merchant::Checkout::CheckoutSessionPBMayfly::load_session_from_mayfly(unsigned long long, boost::shared_ptr) Merchant::Checkout::CheckoutSessionPBMayfly::do_load(Merchant::Checkout::CheckoutSessionToken const&, ForUpdate, boost::shared_ptr) Merchant::Checkout::UnifiedCheckoutSessionPB::load(Merchant::Checkout::CheckoutSessionToken const&, ForUpdate) Merchant::Checkout::CheckoutSessionBLIImpl::get_session_data(Merchant::Checkout::CheckoutSessionToken const&, bool) Merchant::Checkout::CheckoutSessionBLIImpl::get_session_data(String const&, bool) Merchant::PimpWalletBLIImpl::get_wallet(String const&, boost::shared_ptr&, String) Merchant::Payment::ExpressCheckoutALIImpl::get_wallet(String const&, boost::shared_ptr&, String) Rapids::Flows::OneX::StateOneXEC_Start::execute(Rapids::CGIVars const&) Rapids::DecoratedState::execute(Rapids::CGIVars const&) Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::handle_execute(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate const&, Rapids::TransitionRegistry const&, Rapids::State*, String const&, String const&, unsigned long long) Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::process_states(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate const&, Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::ProcessStates, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&, Rapids::TransitionEdge const*) Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::flow_call(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, String const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::call_rapids(Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::RapidsFlowFactory const&, Riprap::DispatchAction const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, String const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::dispatch_loop(Riprap::EPRegistry const&, Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::DispatchAction&, Riprap::WebAppReturn&, String const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::dispatch_wrapper(OutputStream&, Riprap::EPRegistry const&, Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, String const&, bool const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::entry_point(HTTPInterface&, Riprap::CGIVars&, OutputStream&, String const&, String const&) main

Comment: So you're saying the app now redirects to Paypal page with error messages instead of the payment's 'login' page? what does the $response actually contains after you run the purchase function?

Comment: @har2vey, I have updated my question to include the response.

Comment: the content of the [ACK] is 'Success', means usually it'll redirect just fine to Paypal, where user will be presented with login screen or credit card payment option, so what did your $response->redirect() do?

Comment: Everytime I get landed in the paypal page with the error message Sorry — your last action could not be completed.

Comment: From your code implementation of omnipay, it doesn't seem to have any problem, so in this case it might have something to do with your paypal account, have you tried using conventional paypal HTML form submission instead to see if that's working?

Comment: Try clearing your cookies or use private browsing mode, the PayPal development environment seems to get itself stuck every now and then. Also as Ralph mentioned below, you could try using [localtunnel](https://localtunnel.me/) to host your site on a real domain, I'm not sure how PayPal will handle the non-standard port 8000.

Comment: @AdrianMacneil, I tried localtunnel in windows. This worked well. But I see that such tunneling did not preserve my session data maintained by my page local url http://localhost:8000. After successful payment, I retrieve data from session and put the order. I later switched to apache server with localhost as base url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the return/cancel URLS from localhost to an actual server. As Paypal will not be able to return anything to those.

Comment: I hosted my solution at apache. Now with my base domain as localhost, paypal works without any comment. :) Earlier I used php's build-in server that generate http://localhost:8000 for me. Thankn you @Ralph!